# trouble removing an item from a list Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have a Toggle button in my app that when it is pressed it adds an item to a list. and when it is pressed again, it removes the item from the list. the button is working and when you press it for the first time, it ads the item but when it is pressed again, it doesn't remove it.

here is the code from the inkwell to add/remove the item based on the buttons bool.

```
if (context.read<MyProvider>().SelectList[0].buttonBool == false) {
                      context.read<MyProvider>().InfoList.add(Entries(
                          text: 'Hello World',
                          logID: LogID.entry1));
                    } else if (context.read<MyProvider>().SelectList[0].buttonBool == true) {
                      context.read<MyProvider>().MissionInfoList.remove(LogID.entry1);
                    }
```

As you can see, when the button returns false, It adds an Entries to the InfoList which has a Text and a LogID (so it can be found easily if i want to remove it)

but when the button returns true, it is not removing the entry in the list based off an object(the LogID)

I'm new to using lists and am keen to understand what I'm doing wrong here.

thanks so much and any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to filter for the id to find the object you want to delete:

```
context.read<MyProvider>().MissionInfoList.removeWhere((element) => element.logID == LogID.entry1);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I am changing the bool. I just left that bit out of the code. the bool is changing the color of the button and is definitely working. I even ran a print statement on the buttonbool before the code in my question and even when it says true, its still not removing the entry

Comment: Then it is most likely due to your remove method. This method expects an object that is identical to the entry in the list. But you only pass an ID, and not a whole entry, so it doesn't find that. What you can do is to use removeWhere and compare the ID's as condition, see my edited answer.